# Differences between PC, console and mobile versions of Terraria?

Tags: terraria, version-differences, terraria-console

I love the game Terraria for PC and played it for ages. Now I saw Terraria on the PS3-Store and gave it a shot. After some wandering around I saw something like a snow-biome and realised later on, that I was on a floating Island.

I haven't played much of Terraria the last months, but this stuff seems kind of new. In addition I haven't found the (current) differences between the PC and the Consoleversion. Is there just one (upcoming?) Patch missing on the PC? What's included or - like the title said - what are the current differences (besides the splitscreen-feature of course)?

Comment: Both the snow biome and floating islands are part of the PC version. Apparently there is some new gear and a boss in the console versions, but the developer is working on a content update for PC.

Comment: I've read about that patch and was wondering if some of those features are already in the consoleversion. Never seen snow on the PC-version, but as I said before, I haven't played it much in the past.

Comment: Floating islands have always been a part of the PC Terraria.  I think I remember hearing that the console version has waterfalls or something, though.

Comment: I read that too, but couldn't find any further information on it - therefore my question here ;)

Comment: Snow biomes only exist in 1/3 worlds on PC, unless the world was generated some time around Christmas, in which case it will always have a snow biome. Floating islands are always present.

Comment: The console version contains different things that may or may never get included in the pc version. The console version was developed by 505 games, and the PC version is developed by Redigit. There is a patch upcoming for the PC version, but no ETA yet. I don't know if the (currently) console only things will end up in that patch too. AFAIK there are currently more things in the console version then the pc version, but the next patch is going to turn that around again.

Comment: I didn't even knew that they consoleversion was developed by a different studio. Due to that it's not even sure that both versions will stay (nearly) the same as they are at the moment right?

Comment: Redigit has already said that the Console version exclusives will be STAYING on the console version only, but with the upcoming PC update to version 1.2, the PC version will be getting hundreds of new things that the console version wont be seeing. It IS the same game, but the console port was by a different company, and they sort of reserve the right to have their custom console-only stuff stay in their console version.

Comment: Isn't that a question seeking for a list/catalog thingy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The console version have exclusive and new features like new armors, weapons, monster and item.

**Monster:**

- Ocram (Final Boss in the Console Version)

**Weapons:**

- Tizona
- Vulcan Repeater
- Tonbogiri

**Armors:**

- Dragon Armor
- Titan Armor
- Spectral Armor

**Item:**

- Soul of Blight

Moreover, sometimes the recipes for crafting are different.
For example, to create an "Avenger Emblem":

**Desktop:**

- (Warrior/Summoner/Ranger/Sorcerer) Emblem (1)
- Soul of Might (5)
- Soul of Sight (5)
- Soul of Fright (5)

**Console/Mobile:**

- Warrior Emblem (1)
- Ranger Emblem (1)
- Sorcerer Emblem (1)

> Found in Terraria Wiki, a page with "features found exclusively in the console
>   version of Terraria"
>
> [Console Terraria](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Console_Terraria)

Comment: Haven't searched in the wiki. Shame on me. Thanks :)

Comment: So these features will never make it to the PC-version, because they are "exclusive"? Are those although the differences or just the "buy this version because you will never ever get the dragon armor on pc"-things?

Comment: The last update for PC was in January 2012 i think, if they make a new update its possible that they include this new features, it's the same game after all

Comment: @Streuner a new pc update is in the make that is supposed to bring the item count of the pc version to 1000+, with fountains, half height blocks, slopes, new (vanity) armor, new weapons, new blocks, new pets... some new environment with new enemies too. It is supposed to be the biggest patch made for the game (all hardmode content was the previous patch, so we're talking tons of content here)

Answer (score 22):

As of the 1.2 update (November 2013), it's very difficult to compile a full list of the differences, largely because the number of items, enemies, and equipment in the game as a whole is incredibly vast. However, here's a high-level overview:

**PC**

The PC version is the "flagship" version of Terraria, and is the version that receives the most frequent updates. At the present time, it also generally receives new content first.

**Console (PSN/XBLA)**

The console version [has some exclusive items](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Category:Entities_introduced_in_Console-Release), exclusive enemies, and an exclusive boss, as partially listed in [Celta's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/117845/26052).

At its original release, the console version of the game was based on PC version 1.1, with a handful of exclusive items, as previously mentioned. As of November 5, 2013, a portion of the content from the [PC version's 1.2 update](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Version#1.2) has been added to the [console version](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Version#1.2_For_consoles), with the rest of the 1.2 content [slated to be added](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/all-new-updates-have-arrived-for-both-console-and-mobile-versions-of-terraria.120561/) in the coming months. If this pattern continues, it's reasonable to expect that the console versions will receive most of the future PC version content, albeit delayed slightly.

**Mobile (iOS/Android)**

The [mobile version](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_version) features some of the exclusive enemies and items from the console versions, but has some additional limitations: Hardmode is not present, only Small-sized worlds are supported, the monster spawn rate is lower, and so on. As of November 2013, multiplayer is supported, but over Wi-Fi only. A handful of additional exclusive items are present, as well, but they're [mostly cosmetic](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shiny_Black_Slab).

Generally, while most of the core gameplay is present in the mobile version, it is noticeably barer in content and functionality than its console and PC brethren. However, the price is lower to match.

Comment: Note: [They plan to bring the whole of 1.2 to consoles](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/all-new-updates-have-arrived-for-both-console-and-mobile-versions-of-terraria.120561/)