# Is it possible to access hardmode on Android?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I've killed wall of flesh like 5 or 6 times I cant find Pwnhammer or the hallow not even underground corruption!

Can you access hardmode on the android version of Terraria?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/117837/30210

Answer (score 1):

Hardmode is not available on the mobile versions of terraria.

Comment: You can now get hard mode.  See this answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/135378/101016