# What are the pre-hardmode NPCs in terraria console version?

Tags: terraria-console

What are all the pre hard mode NPCs? I need to know how many houses to build for them all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between PC, console and mobile versions of Terraria?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117837/differences-between-pc-console-and-mobile-versions-of-terraria)

Comment: @Ender This question is off-topic because it is possible an answer to it could potentially be included somewhere in an answer to another question?

Comment: @Studoku Yes, EXACTLY, no seriously, I'm not even joking. That is the current 'duplicate policy'. I don't particularly agree with it, but that is how it is done at the moment. Bring it up on the meta if you don't believe me.

Comment: The post you linked to @Ender , that was posted over a year ago, and may be outdated. Furthermore, NPCs are not mentioned in this post. Which may either mean that there are no difference between console and PC version, or they failed to mention it.

Comment: I recognize meta has made a decision, but given that it's a stupid-ass decision I have elected to ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Console_version) it states all the console-exclusive things for Terraria. NPCs are not among them, and therefore are most likely just the same as the PC version. [Here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC#Pre-Hardmode) you can see which NPCs that are possible to spawn pre-hardmode. That is:

- The Guide
- Merchant
- Nurse
- Painter
- Dye Trader
- Demolitionist
- Dryad
- Arms Dealer
- Party Girl
- Stylist
- Angler
- Goblin Tinkerer
- Witch Doctor
- Clothier
- Mechanic

That is 15 NPCs, which means you'll need 15 [houses](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/House).